# Book quantity output problem in library management system

Tags: javascript, php

I am building a library management system using PHP, JavaScript. Each book has a unique code. There will be a system in the form of book borrowing pages. If you input the code of any book, the name of the book and the quantity of the book will come down. I was able to get the name of the book using JavaScript. But I could not bring the amount of books.

**issue-book.php**

```
function getbook() {
 $("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "get_book.php",
data:'bookid='+$("#bookid").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
$("#get_book_name").html(data);
$("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}


//function for quantity
function getquantity() {
$("#loaderIcon").show();
jQuery.ajax({
url: "get_quantity.php",
data:'bookid2='+$("#bookid2").val(),
type: "POST",
success:function(data){
$("#get_quantity").html(data);
$("#loaderIcon").hide();
},
error:function (){}
});
}

</script> 
<style type="text/css">
.others{
color:red;
}

</style>


</head>
<body>
  <!------MENU SECTION START-->
<?php include('includes/header.php');?>
<!-- MENU SECTION END-->
<div class="content-wra
<div class="content-wrapper">
     <div class="container">
    <div class="row pad-botm">
        <div class="col-md-12">
             <h4 class="header-line">Issue a New Book</h4>
            
                        </div>

 </div>
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-10 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 col-md-offset-1"">
<div class="panel panel-info">
<div class="panel-heading">
Issue a New Book
</div>
<div class="panel-body">
<form role="form" method="post">

<div class="form-group">
<label>Student id<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
<input class="form-control" type="text" name="studentid" id="studentid" onBlur="getstudent()" 
autocomplete="off"  required />
</div>

<div class="form-group">
<span id="get_student_name" style="font-size:16px;"></span> 
</div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <label>ISBN Number or Book Title<span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
 <input class="form-control" type="text" name="booikid" id="bookid" onBlur="getquantity()"  
 required="required" />
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <select  class="form-control" name="bookdetails" id="get_book_name" readonly></select>
 </div>

 <div class="form-group">
 <select  class="form-control" name="quantity" id="get_quantity" readonly></select>
 </div>

<button type="submit" name="issue" id="submit" class="btn btn-info">Issue Book </button>

                                </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                        </div>

    </div>

</div>
</div>
```

**get_quantity.php**

```
<?php 
require_once("includes/config.php");
if(!empty($_POST["bookid2"])) {
$bookid2=$_POST["bookid2"];

$sql ="SELECT Quantity, id FROM tblbooks WHERE (ISBNNumber=:bookid2)";
$query= $dbh -> prepare($sql);
$query-> bindParam(':bookid2', $bookid2, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query-> execute();
$results = $query -> fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);
$cnt=1;
if($query -> rowCount() > 0)
{
foreach ($results as $result) {?>
<option value="<?php echo htmlentities($result->id);?>"><?php echo htmlentities($result- 
>Quantity);?></option>
<b>Book Name :</b> 
<?php  
echo htmlentities($result->Quantity);
echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',false);</script>";
}
 }
else{?>

<option class="others"> Invalid ISBN Number</option>
<?php
echo "<script>$('#submit').prop('disabled',true);</script>";
}
}



?>
```

[image]

Comment: `$_POST['bookid2']` does not exist, try with `$_POST['quantity']`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution

```
      //function for quantity
    function getquantity() {
      $("#loaderIcon").show();
  jQuery.ajax({
     url: "get_quantity.php",
   data:'bookid2='+$("#bookid").val(),
   type: "POST",
     success:function(data){
  $("#get_quantity").html(data);
  $("#loaderIcon").hide();
  },
  error:function (){}
   });
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not specifically an answer to your question, but you might make life a lot easier for yourself if you add some error detection. For instance in your AJAX calls your error reporting now looks like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({ ... },
    error: function (){}
});
```

That is completely useless. Why not do:

```
jQuery.ajax({ ... },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
               alert("ERROR: " + textStatus);                 
           }
});
```

That way you know immediately if your AJAX call had a problem, or not.

Same with [PDOStatement::execute()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) that returns `TRUE` on success and `FALSE` on failure. That's useful to know. You can give yourself some feedback.

You could also use your [browser's developer tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Common_questions/What_are_browser_developer_tools) to see what your Javascript code is doing.

Debugging code is often as much work as writing it in the first place. Why not make that slightly easier for yourself?